# Negative Loss In Keras Convolutional AutoEncoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am trying to implement the AutoEncoder developed on the keras documentation webpage (https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) that is using convolutional layers. On the example they use it for the MNIST dataset flattened (reshaped from 3 channels RGB to 1) but I want to use all 3 channels. The dataset I am using has different dimentions. So, what I tried to do is just changing the parts of the code in order to output and image from the decoder with dims = (128, 128, 3) but the problem is that I get negative loss (deeply negative) and I do not know what is happening. This is the chunk of code where I do so:

```
input_img = keras.Input(shape= input_dim)

x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)


x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = layers.UpSampling3D((2))(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = layers.UpSampling3D((2))(x)
decoded = layers.Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = keras.Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')


autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                epochs=50,
                batch_size=128,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
```

Input dim is equal to (128, 128, 3) and my data dimentions x_train.shape, x_test.shape, are equal to ((6000, 128, 128, 3), (1200, 128, 128, 3)).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the range of your inputs?

Comment: They are not normalized, so from 0 to 255. @Dr.Snoopy

Comment: That is what produces the negative loss, just think of how the binary cross-entropy is computed (there is a 1 - y term). The loss assumes [0, 1] ranged labels.

Comment: hahaha, you are right! Inputs should be normalized! @Dr.Snoopy. Totally my bad. I am gonna change that and see what happens